# DynamoDB ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits vs Consumed CloudWatch Metrics for 1 second Period

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I am confused by this live chart, ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits is exceeding the provisioned units, while "consumed" is way below. Do I have a real problem or not?
This seems to only show for the

One Second Period

[image]

One Minute Period

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your period is wrong for the metrics. DynamoDB emits metrics at the following periods:

ConsumedCapacity: 1 min
ProvisionedCapacity: 5 min

For ConsumedCapacity you should divide the metric by the period but only at a minimum of 1min.

Exceeding provisioned capacity for short periods of time is fine, as burst capacity will allow you to do so. But if you exceed it for long periods it will lead to throttling.

Comment: are you saying AWS can't have data down to resolution of seconds? then why does it show 1 second, 10 seconds, etc on the column of "Period", that would be misleading.

Comment: I uploaded some better screenshots

Comment: I didn't say AWS can't have 1 second resolution, I stated the frequency that DynamoDB emits metrics. The reason your red line is dotted is because you're choosing 1 second for a metric that is only recorded every 5mins.

Comment: I got confirmation from AWS support, as you pointed out, CloudWatch metric is only as granular as 1 minute, so they should not offer period options as seconds in the "Period" column.

Comment: CloudWatch does not create service specific dashboards, this is why you see granularity which is not correct for DynamoDB. Feel free to leave your feedback with Support who can bring it to the Engineering team.